# why do I have a goroutine if I have a return

Tags: html, go, goroutine

Hello I am actually building a website which has to transform a text to some ascii art with a template

So if I am waiting for a return why do I have this error:

```
2021/04/02 23:50:57 http: panic serving [::1]:64796: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
goroutine 20 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc00009d040)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x5c8040, 0xc0001ae4e0)
        C:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x3e9
Ascii-art-web/AsciiArts.AsciiMain(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0001802c0, 0x659920, 0x2, 0x5e7c7d)
        C:/Users/kioki/go/src/Ascii-art-web/AsciiArts/asciimain.go:38 +0x766
main.main.func1(0x65e4c0, 0xc0001a82a0, 0xc0001a2100)
        C:/Users/kioki/go/src/Ascii-art-web/server.go:42 +0x1ca
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000088d30, 0x65e4c0, 0xc0001a82a0, 0xc0001a2100)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x4b
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x840920, 0x65e4c0, 0xc0001a82a0, 0xc0001a2100)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1b7
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc000126000, 0x65e4c0, 0xc0001a82a0, 0xc0001a2100)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xaa
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00009d040, 0x65eb40, 0xc000184000)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36d
```

for those who have seen this post I am sorry the panic line got erased by the ```

Here is the asciimain.go file l38 = `s := GetBanner(chars[0])`

```
func AsciiMain(font string,str string) []string {
    chars := []byte(str)
    s := GetBanner(chars[0])
    for i := 1;i < len(chars); i++ {
        g := GetBanner(chars[i])
        for j := 0;j < 8; j++ {
            s[j] = s[j]+g[j]
        }
    }
    return s
}
```

the str is sent by the user on the website here it was `t`
and the server.go file:

```
http.HandleFunc("/",func( w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    details := AsciiSubmit{
        Color:   r.FormValue("colorpicker"),
        Font: r.FormValue("font"),
        Text: r.FormValue("message"),
    }
    fstr := AsciiArts.AsciiMain(details.Font,details.Text)

    data := Page{"AsciiArts",details.Color,fstr[0],fstr[1],fstr[2],fstr[3],fstr[4],fstr[5],fstr[6],fstr[7]}

    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", data)
})
```

The get banner func is a map with all the ascii art in it:

```
func GetBanner(stri byte) []string {
    font := make(map[byte][]string, 100)
    font[32] = []string{
        "      ",
        "      ",
        "      ",
        "      ",
        "      ",
        "      ",
        "      ",
        "      ",
    }
    font[33] = []string{
        " _  ",
        "| | ",
        "| | ",
        "| | ",
        "|_| ",
        "(_) ",
        "    ",
        "    ",
    }
    ...
    font[126] = []string{
        " /\\/| ",
        "|/\\/ ",
        "      ",
        "      ",
        "      ",
        "      ",
        "      ",
        "      ",
    }
    if v, ok := font[stri]; ok {
        return v
    }
    return font[32]
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the actual error, just the stack trace that shows where the error occurred. (The error should be just before this in your output and start with `panic: `).

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code to produce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `http.HandleFunc` might execute it self multiple times so here is a way to bypass the problem:

```
http.HandleFunc("/",func( w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        fmt.Println("ici")
        tmpl, _ := textTemplate.ParseFiles("./html/index.html")
        details := AsciiSubmit{
            Color:   r.FormValue("colorpicker"),
            Font: r.FormValue("font"),
            Text: r.FormValue("message"),
        }
        if len(details.Text) != 0 {
            fstr := AsciiArts.AsciiMain(details.Font,details.Text)
            data := Page{"AsciiArts",details.Color,fstr[0],fstr[1],fstr[2],fstr[3],fstr[4],fstr[5],fstr[6],fstr[7]}

            tmpl.Execute(w, data)
        } else {
            data := Page{Title: "AsciiArts"}

            tmpl.Execute(w, data)
        }


    })
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a runtime panic. Why it panicked should also be printed somewhere before this stack dump.

The HTTP server handles each request in its own goroutine. If this wasn't the case, the http server could have served only one client at a time.

If you show what the error is, we can provide more information about how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: sorry the three ` erased the panic line

Comment: You have an index out of range error here:   C:/Users/kioki/go/src/Ascii-art-web/AsciiArts/asciimain.go:38 +0x766

Comment: yes but no it cannot be that because
`chars := []byte(str)
s := GetBanner(chars[0])`
the get banner is the right line but the string is 5 characters long

Comment: That's what the exception says. Show the code around that area.

Comment: Evidence suggests str is empty. If you are calling this from a web page it migh be failing when the client calls the server to get options. You are not checking the http method so you do not know if this is a get or a post

Comment: when I use `fmt.Println(str)` it actually print the `t` in the terminal

Comment: @rob_runner, str being the empty string is the only way to produce this panic. It's easy to miss the empty line that Println prints. This is client supplied data and thus *must* be validated no matter what (it will fail for the request to /favicon.ico at least). Just check the length and move on.

Comment: @Peter but on the site the ascii actually prints but there is this error and some spaces are missing

Comment: I suspect there are multiple calls to the server and one is failing. Print out the http method in the request and see.

Comment: yes the server was called three time so I did a method to avoid the problem